Is asking for help with new proofs on-topic?
Is it appropriate and on-topic to ask for help with provable security?
For example, would it be reasonable to ask for technical assistance in applying the Leftover Hash Lemma to show that a sum is indistinguishable from uniform?

My intuition would say: Yes, if all you need is clarification wrt techniques or only small steps are missing or you want only a proof-sketch. We won't solve homework nor make complicated proofs in answers.
